# SVG line graph curved lines, on peaks and troughs

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to get a line to curve on peaks and troughs, however I am a little confused with SVG path as they dont quite flow right.

I have an image to explain what I mean. As you can see there are 2 lines. One straight (showing correct data, ie turns on the points) and one curved (wrong, turns after the points).

[image]

What I need to do is get them to turn on the actual points as such.

[image]

The code I have is like this.

```
        <g>
            <path
                class="line"
                stroke-width="1.5px"
                d="M50 90, 100 100, T150 190, T200 200, T250 180, T300 150"
                fill="none"
                stroke="#7aa3e5"
            ></path>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path
                class="line"
                stroke-width="1.5px"
                d="M50 90, 100 100, 150 190, 200 200, 250 180, 300 150"
                fill="none"
                stroke="green"
            ></path>
        </g>
```

Would I need to add extra data points to get better curves, if so, would there be some kind of algorithm that can manage that? Or a better way to do curves that are not so drastic.

Best regards and thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: This seemed the most easy way to get cool curves. https://bl.ocks.org/gordlea/27370d1eea8464b04538e6d8ced39e89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Bézier Curves?
Bézier Curves is difficult, But, it's useful once you get used to using it.

If you don't know about Bézier Curves, first read the link below. Then you practice at GIMP or some image editor software. Second, Drow what you want to express. Finally, Export it as SVG.

Of curse, SVG Bézier Curves can be used text editor, but it's difficult.

[Bézier Curves GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Bezier_Selections/)
[Bézier Curves MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#B%C3%A9zier_Curves)

I hope this post will help you.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it needs to be dynamic. So the graph will change.

Comment: Then, the only way I know is to learn Bézier Curves and Using it by Bézier Curves tutorial above. Though it needs to be dynamic, by using image editor software, you can understand how  Bézier Curves works. After you understand, just code!

Comment: Thanks, your links were super helpful. I think I am going to try and use d3 charts. They have super cool functions that build line graphs for you and have curve functions also.